# MS-WORD - Insert as icon for image files

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

Is there a default setting to have ALL files that are inserted to be inserted as an object?

For example, when dragging and dropping an image file into Word 2003, the image is rendered. However this is not what I want, I would like it to appear as an icon.

I know this can be done manually by going to Insert followed by object and choosing the "Create from file" tab, however with multiple image files to be inserted this is time consuming. Is there a defaulted setting for this?

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You might be able to create a macro that does some or all of the repetitive steps for you. Could also write something in VBA that does it for you.

Comment: Yeah, the answers I found on Google stated the use of a macro too... Weird thing is, the user that asked me this question supposedly was able to insert images as icon by default, so I assumed that someone changed their settings. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It is 2019 and this is still the same problem, tried with latest word available as of September of 2019 and still the same problem.